# Pycharm IDE Broke pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pycharm

I recently deleted pycharm, and when I type `pip` in command prompt, it says:
`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\Admin\pycharmprojects\coronagame\venv\scripts\python.exe"  "C:\WINDOWS\system32\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.`

What can I do to get pip back? I really need it for my school project

Comment: Does this work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67642714/1028772

Comment: pip should not be in WINDOWS directory, please add your PATH environment variable to the question, it can help